# How can I check if there is a touch on either half of the screen in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a spriteKit game where there is something moving, and I want to make it so that if I touch the right half of the screen it turns right, and if I touch the left half, it turns left. How can I constantly get where all touches are on the screen?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like the following

Objective-C

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if (touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2) {
        // Left side of the screen
    } else {
        // Right side of the screen
    }
}
```

Swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {
        // Left side of the screen
    } else {
        // Right side of the screen
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to check if there is a touch on each half of the screen in the update method though